# when I write SELECT ~1; on Postgresql it gives me -2 as a result. What is the reason of this? And it keeps going for ~4 and -5 etc

Tags: postgresql, integer, tilde

I was looking for sql basics and I decided to write `SELECT ~1;` on postgresql and as a result it returned `-2`. When i tried this for bigger number it always returned me integer's next integer and negative (~300 and -301). I wonder what's the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` evidently is the **[bitwise negation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html)** operator. 1 = 0b00001, ~1 = 0b111...110 = -2.

This is also called the *ones' complement*. As you know the numbers use *two's complement* as representation for negative numbers (as then -0 == 0):

```
-x == ~x+1
~x == -x-1
```